Why is adding files to .gitignore deleting it in remote?
I am just playing around and trying to understand .gitnore and how it works. I noticed the previously tracked items, after adding to .gitignore are deleted in remote after pushing the commit.
I have a previously tracked appsettings.json and appsettings.Dev.json added to .gitignore by right clicking on it, and selecting Ignore and Untrack item on Visual Studio. This effectively adds the items to the .gitignore file. But I noticed that once the changes are committed and pushed to remote, the files are deleted on remote. Is that the intended behavior? Or am I missing something?

As the filename says, .gitignore means git will ignore the files or directories added to it, not tracking anymore.
For more details check git documentation, there's a section just for gitignore
